# Getting "500 Internal Server Error" while posting a request to the MongoDB using Mongoose transaction

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am developing an online survey application based on React, NodeJS, Express, MongoDB and Mongoose. I face this issue when I wanted to post a request (via a form submission) to the MongoDB via Mongoose and I always get error message "Creating answer failed, please try again." with my code to recognize it is related to error happened with DB. I can see the request body is created actually in payload of request; however, the document is not created in the MongoDB. Please refer to the related code as below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-glitter-885pg?file=/src/backend/model/text-question.js

Comment: Sometimes the error occurs whenever the datatype the database is expecting for its field is not of the same. So, can you validate the data type sent in the POST request and the data type accepted by the field are the same ?

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the response. I checked the datatype of my text-question model and respective field of object in the POST request. They are both "String".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to `push` the `_id` of the `createdAnswer` instead of the whole object after its creation in the `text-controller.js` file:

```
...
    const sess = await mongoose.startSession();
    sess.startTransaction();
    await createdAnswer.save({ session: sess });
    // Add createdAnswer id to the specific user
    user.answers.push(createdAnswer._id); // <- CHANGE THIS LINE
    await user.save({ session: sess });
    await sess.commitTransaction();
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and help. It doesn't work after I tried your suggestion. But I noticed that the "answers" array in the user object couldn't add and update the new answer which is created after the POST request.

Comment: In addition, there is a strange behavior that the "FIRST" POST request for generation of user and answer can be achieved successfully; however, the following POST request for the answer will cause the error message "500 Creating answer failed, please try again.".

Comment: Try to edit your error messages to display the actual error thrown like this `HttpError("Creating answer failed, please try again. " + err)`. You can use the exception message for debugging.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I figured the issue out. The reason is that I am using mongoose-unique-validator in the User model for validating the uniqueness of user. This causes a TypeError.